# Developing a 64-bit DLL and 32-bit DLL in the same solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, 32bit-64bit

We are developing a DLL for both 32-bit and 64-bit targets. This DLL references a library in WinDDK. Therefore, for our 32-bit target DLL, we must reference the 32-bit DDK library and for the 64-bit target DLL, we must reference the 64-bit DDK library.

What is the best way to do that? Right now, in our code we have:

```
#pragma comment (lib , "c:\winddk\i386\...");
```

but for an x64 target, that path is incorrect. We do not want to modify these paths manually in our code as that is very error prone. If it matters, we're on VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `#ifdef`:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
    #pragma comment (lib , "c:\winddk\x64\...")
#else
    #pragma comment (lib , "c:\winddk\i386\...")
#endif
```

[`_WIN64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) is a Microsoft-specific predefined macro.